# Magento 2 - join checkout steps

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

In one page checkout I want to make one step instead two separate steps (default is one for shipping, one for payments methods). So I made changes in

- `checkout_index_index` - removed payment-steps and moved `item name="payment" xsi:type="array"` to shipping-step
- in `LayoutProcessor.process` changed payment localization to shipping-step
- in `js/view/payment.js` removed `stepNavigator.registerStep` and added `this.navigate()` which calls `getPaymentInformation()` and sets block as visible

It worked out but I'm getting message that there are no payments. I think problem is in loading payments list. When are two steps, second step (this with payment)  is loaded after clicking on button below shipping methods. This button

- sends address data to server (`setShippingInformation`) by calling url `/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/xxxx/payment-information`
- get back payments list (and `paymentService.setPaymentMethods` is called)
- and then shows second step (`stepNavigator.next()`)

So before showing second step, payments are loaded from server. I could call this url `/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/xxxx/payment-information` but it requires address data in parameters. So it looks like payments methods can be resolved only after address is filled? But I want to show payments methods just after loading without looking at address.

At the beginnig of `payments.js` I noticed also this code `paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(window.checkoutConfig.paymentMethods));` It looks like that this code also loads payments list, so maybe I can assign somewhere in php code payments list to `checkoutConfig`?

Does anybody known how do this?